# Center all navbar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to center my menu in Bootstrap, but I can't center the logo aside the links.

This is the idea:

http://postimg.org/image/gfi2lups1/

I want to change the above menu to the below menu.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpMbLY?editors=100

```
<div class="container-fluid sin-padding navbar-fixed-top">
<nav class="menu_top navbar-default menu_top" role="navigation">
  <!-- Encabezado del menu -->

  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">

      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>

    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/puma_logo.png" /></a>
  </div>


  <!-- Cuerpo del menu -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">


    <ul class="nav separacion-nav navbar-nav">

      <li class="excepcion"><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown excepcion">
        <a href="#" style="background-color: white;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">SERVICES <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="submenu-vertical menu-hover dropdown-menu dropdown-sin-fondo">
          <li><a href="#">Cargo surveys</a></li>
            <li class="submenu-lista"><a onmouseover="this.style.color='black'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#989898'" style="color:#989898;" class="submenu-submenu" href="#">Loss / Damage Survey</a></li>
              <li class="submenu-lista"><a onmouseover="this.style.color='black'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#989898'" style="color:#989898;" class="submenu-submenu" href="#">Pre-Shipment Survey</a></li>
              <li class="submenu-lista"><a onmouseover="this.style.color='black'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#989898'" style="color:#989898;" class="submenu-submenu" href="#">Loading Survey</a></li>  
              <li class="submenu-lista"><a onmouseover="this.style.color='black'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#989898'" style="color:#989898;" class="submenu-submenu" href="#">Discharge Survey</a></li> 
              <li class="submenu-lista"><a onmouseover="this.style.color='black'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#989898'" style="color:#989898;" class="submenu-submenu" href="#">Outturn / Condition Survey</a></li> 
              <li class="submenu-lista"><a onmouseover="this.style.color='black'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#989898'" style="color:#989898;" class="submenu-submenu" href="#">Quantity Survey</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Containers and cargo in containers surveys</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Heavy lift, oversized and projects cargos surveys</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Hull and machinery surveys</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Claims handling</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="excepcion"><a href="#">SPECIALIZED AUTOMOBILE SURVEYS</a></li>
      <li class="excepcion"><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img class="blocked" src="img/lloyd.jpg"/></a><div class="clearfix"></div></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You should post your CSS as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing your wrapper div class from `container-fluid` to just `container`. Container-fluid spans the whole width of the available viewport while container has pre-configured widths based on the xs,sm,md,lg properties of bootstrap.

So change this:

`<div class="container-fluid sin-padding navbar-fixed-top">`
to
`<div class="container sin-padding navbar-fixed-top">`

I believe this will produce the desired effect as shown in your image.